# How to get the arguments passed to various calls from call_args_list?

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm trying to use call_args_list to get the arguments passed to a certain function when it is called multiple times. I'm using this:

```
call_args_list = mock.add_row.call_args_list
```

Then I get a list that looks like this: `[call('A', []), call('B', []), call('C', ['err'])]`.

If I only want to check that the second call doesn't have an error in the second argument and the third does, I need to somehow access the items within the call. Does anyone know how can I peel these call objects to get the items inside?

Answer (score 4):

```
import unittest

import mock


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_func(self):
        m = mock.MagicMock()
        m.add_row('A', [])
        m.add_row('B', [])
        m.add_row('C', ['err'])

        calls = m.add_row.call_args_list

        _first_arg, second_arg = calls[1][0]
        self.assertNotEqual(second_arg, ['err'])

        _first_arg, second_arg = calls[2][0]
        self.assertEqual(second_arg, ['err'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be (well) documented, but `mock` defines a subclass of `tuple` named `_Call`, instances of which are what you see in `call_args_list`. The first element is the name of the function, the second is a tuple of positional arguments, and the third a dict of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
def test_call_args(self):
    m = mock.Mock()
    m.add_row('A', ['a', 'aa'])
    m.add_row('B', ['b', 'bb', 'bbb'])
    m.add_row('C', ['c', 'cc', 'ccc', 'err'])

    # args is a tuple, the second call
    args, kwargs = m.add_row.call_args_list[1]
    # the second arg is a list
    self.assertTrue('err' not in args[1])

    # third call
    args, kwargs = m.add_row.call_args_list[2]
    self.assertTrue('err' in args[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of digging into these `_Call` objects, but only to some extent. What if, for example, a parameter in a called mocked method is itself a `Mock`?

Consider this:

```
def test_create_and_show_main_window_should_make_main_window_vis(qtbot):
    with mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication'):
        with mock.patch.object(MainWindow.the(), 'show') as mock_show:
            with mock.patch('sys.exit') as mock_exit:
                
                main_window_class.create_and_show_main_window()
        
    mock_show.assert_called_once()
    mock_exit.assert_called_once()
    call = mock_exit.call_args_list[0]
    call_arg = call.args[0]
    assert call_arg._extract_mock_name() == 'QApplication().exec()'
```

In the above I want to test the following lines in my app code:

```
app_instance = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow.the().show()
sys.exit(app_instance.exec())
```

... it turns out that, in the above, `call_arg` is of type `unittest.mock.MagicMock` and that `repr(call_arg)` is "`<MagicMock name='QApplication().exec()' id='139817836711216'>"`.

A `MagicMock` has a `name` attribute, but if you try to use it directly it will create a new `MagicMock` automatically rather than returning it: `MagicMock`s are slippery, powerful objects. Fortunately, as illustrated above, the method `_extract_mock_name` has been provided to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

simply , you can access the call using   call_args_list[0] or call_args_list[1] .. depending on the element you want then : accces the params with [-1 ]
so in your case :
call_args_list = [call('A', []), call('B', []), call('C', ['err'])]
third_call = call_args_list[2] will return call('C', ['err']) then you do third_call[-1] that will return ('C', ['err']) the you chack what you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).